# SentryClient closed unexpectedly before capturing the event and sending it to sentry. ERROR: {"detail":"empty envelope"} API returned 400 ERROR

Tags: scala, log4j, log4j2, databricks, sentry

```
    %scala

import io.sentry.{Sentry, SentryOptions}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val sentryOptions = new SentryOptions()
  sentryOptions.setDsn(sys.env.getOrElse("SENTRY_DSN", "REDACTED"))
  sentryOptions.setEnvironment(sys.env.getOrElse("SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT", "dev"))
  sentryOptions.setRelease(sys.env.getOrElse("SENTRY_RELEASE", "dev"))
  sentryOptions.setDebug(true)
Sentry.init(sentryOptions)
Sentry.captureException(new Throwable())

Sentry.flush(2000L)
```

running above piece if code in the databricks notebook logs this error below. could't figure out the root cause tried. nothing much is there as part of the integration but really got bugged due to unlimited failed attempts :

```
INFO: Initializing SDK with DSN: 'REDACTED'
INFO: No outbox dir path is defined in options.
INFO: GlobalHubMode: 'false'
DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration removed.
INFO: Closing SentryClient.
DEBUG: Shutting down
DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration enabled: true
DEBUG: default UncaughtExceptionHandler class='com.databricks.DatabricksMain$DBUncaughtExceptionHandler'
DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration installed.
DEBUG: Capturing event: bdf91ad1b3e1451093b72970aab03bfd
INFO: Session is null on scope.withSession
ERROR: Request failed, API returned 400
ERROR: {"detail":"empty envelope"}
import io.sentry.{Sentry, SentryOptions}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
sentryOptions: io.sentry.SentryOptions = io.sentry.SentryOptions@5e0d7239
```

Comment: are you using GSON as a dependency? the minimum required version is 2.7
if you're not using Gradle/Maven as dependency management, you need to pull this dependency in and be sure it's not older than that

Comment: i have installed io.sentry:1.7.30 and gson:2.8.5 maven libs in the databricks cluster

Comment: looks like you're using the Sentry >= 4.x API but installing Sentry 1.7.30 jars? be sure about your dependencies and libs https://sentry.io/for/scala/
or this https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-spark